# Scaling scene for different aspect ratio

Tags: unity-game-engine

In unity I am trying to scale the scene to fit the screen size without loosing it’s aspect ratio. I have tried one solution of aspect utility but it is not working properly, it is showing black strips and so UI do not look good.
I want to target both devices android as well as iPad( e.g 16:9, 4:3 ratio)
Can anybody guide me how to achieve scaling on any kind of devices?

Comment: weird, scene should be automatically resized to the device resolution...

Comment: @Roberto: But I do not want to loose the ratio as well

Comment: You can adjust the ratio. I think you probably can do whatever you want using `Screen.height`, `Screen.width`, `Camera.aspect` and mainly `Camera.rect`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NGUI plugin and attach UIStretchScript on the Image.

Comment: can you provide more details on this? sorry but i am new to unity.

Comment: Also I want to scale the scene and not GUI.

Answer (score 0):

try this...name the script as "camera.cs"....add it to your camera...and paste the following code :

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class camera : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    // set the desired aspect ratio (the values in this example are
    // hard-coded for 16:9, but you could make them into public
    // variables instead so you can set them at design time)
    float targetaspect = 16.0f / 9.0f;

    // determine the game window's current aspect ratio
    float windowaspect = (float)Screen.width / (float)Screen.height;

    // current viewport height should be scaled by this amount
    float scaleheight = windowaspect / targetaspect;

    // obtain camera component so we can modify its viewport
    Camera camera = GetComponent<Camera>();

    // if scaled height is less than current height, add letterbox
    if (scaleheight < 1.0f)
    {  
        Rect rect = camera.rect;

        rect.width = 1.0f;
        rect.height = scaleheight;
        rect.x = 0;
        rect.y = (1.0f - scaleheight) / 2.0f;

        camera.rect = rect;
    }
    else // add pillarbox
    {
        float scalewidth = 1.0f / scaleheight;

        Rect rect = camera.rect;

        rect.width = scalewidth;
        rect.height = 1.0f;
        rect.x = (1.0f - scalewidth) / 2.0f;
        rect.y = 0;

        camera.rect = rect;
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There's only two ways to maintain the game's aspect ratio with differing viewport aspect ratios. First, stretching in a given direction, which is never a good option. Second, letterboxing (black bars), which can affect usability, especially on handheld screens. My recommendation would be to allow the game view to scale according to the screen's aspect ratio (which I think is the default functionality in Unity), and design the GUI to be responsive to the screen size (i.e. don't draw GUI elements with pixel specific coords, but with coords relative to the screen size).